# TinyMCE onSaveContent happening multiple times

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Okay, I feel like after a few hours of research and exhaustive troubleshooting I've done my due diligence and can ask for help here.

I have multiple TinyMCE Editor instances on a page.  Here's the initialization code:

```
 $('.simpletinymce').tinymce({
    // Location of TinyMCE script
    script_url : '/tm/tiny_mce.js',

    // General options
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "save",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,cancel,newdocument,
    |,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,
    |,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,undo,redo,|,bullist,numlist",

    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",

    submit_patch:false,

    //Callback function to be executed upon saving
    setup : function(ed) {
          ed.onSaveContent.add(function(ed, o) {

          // code to execute
              alert("Your changes have been saved!");

          });
    }
)};
```

The problem I am having is that, when a Save button is clicked on any one of these forms, I get that "Your changes have been saved!" alert for every single editor on the page.

Two editors, two alerts.  Three editors, three alerts (etc...)

What's particularly confusing is that if I change the initialization from the current class

```
$('.simpletinymce')
```

...to an individual ID reference for each instance...

```
$('#Instance1')
$('#Instance2')
$('#Instance3')
(etc.)
```

...I get the same results.  An alert for every TinyMCE instance on the page.

Has anyone run into this before, or know how to resolve this?

If I rip out any more hair I'm going to have to move down to my eye-brows :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you call `triggerSave()` save on all tinymce instance will be called.
What you want is to call `save` on the editor instance of your choice.